# jQuery edit-in-place with dynamic content

Tags: jquery

On my website I add elements to DOM this way

```
$('#header').load('header.html #template');
```

So I load the contents of an external html file into the DOM. Then I call

```
$('.edit').editInPlace({
    callback: function(){
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

The loaded content contains a `h2 with edit css` class.

But there is no reaction at all. I tried many edit-in-place plugins. With all I had the same problem. Any ideas why? How do I solve this?

Comment: do you have `jquery.editinplace.js` imported?

Comment: Use `console.log('test');` instead and monitor browser console status. The alert might break the plugin. If you can setup a test page that will help a lot.

Comment: Of course it is importent. console.log does not log anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `jquery.load()` method is async, then although you are calling the `editInPlace` after you run the load method, the content is still not there. you should use a callback:

```
$('#header').load('header.html #template',function(){
    $('.edit').editInPlace({
        callback: function(){
        alert("test");
       }
    });
});
```